# Play framework application Authenticating using ADFS?

Tags: playframework, adfs

We are working on a website using Play 2.0

How can I authenticate using ADFS?

Any example or steps would be of great use.

Thanks in Advance,

Kishore Jandhyala

Comment: What is ADFS? Please give some information

Comment: ADFS stands for Active Directory Federation Services (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services)